# Window is in random offsets on page refresh

Tags: javascript, css, gsap, window-object

I'm using GSAP animations in a project and I keep running into this bug where upon page refresh the window will sometimes be in random places.  When this happens I just type in window.pageXOffset to see where it's at. This sometimes happens with the Y axis as well.  I'm using Chrome, but I've tested it out on Safari and it hasn't happened but it's a totally random bug.  It usually will happen when my inspector is out and I've been clicking around A LOT!   Clicking the 'empty cache and hard reload' button has fixed it every time.  This is a wordpress project too, so I'm not sure when the scripts get loaded if that matters.  Anyone know what's going on???